# Migrating from SQL Server to MySQL using MySQL Workbench tool

Tags: sql-server, mysql-5.1, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to migrate few tables from SQL Server to MySQL using MySQL Workbench migration wizard. All work fine for structure migrations but when I go to the data migration section it throws an error for one table:

> ERROR: `dbo`.`Documents`:SQLExecDirect(SELECT [DocumentID],
>   [CategoryID], CAST([DocumentName] as NVARCHAR(255)) as [DocumentName],
>   [Active], [NavigatorID], CAST([DocumentText] as NTEXT) as
>   [DocumentText], [UseSubtitle], CAST([DocumentSubtitle] as
>   NVARCHAR(255)) as [DocumentSubtitle], CAST([DocumentPlainText] as
>   NTEXT) as [DocumentPlainText], [DocumentType], CAST([DocumentLink] as
>   NVARCHAR(255)) as [DocumentLink], [Sitemap], CAST([SubtitleImage] as
>   NVARCHAR(255)) as [SubtitleImage], CAST([MetaTags] as NVARCHAR(8000))
>   as [MetaTags], CAST([MetaDescription] as NVARCHAR(8000)) as
>   [MetaDescription], [AccessLevel] FROM [ctool_test].[dbo].[Documents]):
>   42000:1131:[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The size
>   (8000) given to the convert specification 'nvarchar' exceeds the
>   maximum allowed for any data type (4000).
>
> 2131:[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The size (8000)
>   given to the convert specification 'nvarchar' exceeds the maximum
>   allowed for any data type (4000).

Based on that what I can understand it limits columns with `nvarchar` data to max size of 4000 when MySQL can handle 65535.

Any clue how I can get this to work?

Thanks

Comment: What are the source columns (NVARCHAR(4000) or NVARCHAR(MAX))? How are you building that SELECT statement?

Comment: Source column has text data and is set as NVARCHAR(8000). Select statement is done by MySQL Workbench so I even don't need to touch queries (but I can save them for command line execution if needed)

Comment: There is no such thing as NVARCHAR(8000). Where are you seeing this?

Comment: Through MySQL Workbench migration wizard - Create Schemata step.

Comment: Well MySQL Workbench does not have a very good grasp of SQL Server data types.

Comment: It looks like I need to create table manually in that case and set it as VARCHAR instead of NVARCHAR then I need to set same data type in data migration part.

Comment: Why VARCHAR instead of NVARCHAR? If you have Unicode data, you will lose it.

Comment: I have checked MSSQL server (Management Studio this time not that MySQL Workbench) and for those columns data are stored as VARCHAR(8000) so based on that I can create same for MySQL side. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, if the source is varchar there is no reason to cast to nvarchar during migration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, since you have data currently stored in SQL Server, and it's already in an `NVARCHAR` column, then either it's an `NVARCHAR <= 4000` (in which case you can't lose any data, and should just change all instances of `NVARCHAR(8000)` to `NVARCHAR(4000)`), or it's an `NVARCHAR(MAX)` column, in which case you change all instances of `NVARCHAR(8000)` to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. Or just leave out those `CASTs` - do you really need them?

As an aside, you should probably change `as NTEXT` to `as NVARCHAR(MAX)` as well.

Comment: OK, got this to work following all answers above.